# Flutter: Automatic refactor in VS Code after renaming directory or changing path

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am running Flutter on VS Code and often make changes within my Lib directory where I rename files or change their location within the directory. After making the change, all my import statements give me the error `Target of URI doesn't exist` and force me to manually update each import statement with the correct file path to the resource file. Is there a way for VS Code to automatically detect and update the file path in all dependent files whenever there is a change to that file's name or location?

Edit: I use absolute paths in my project: `import 'package:Project/model/example.dart'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following line to your `settings.json`  to automatically update import file paths: `"dart.previewUpdateImportsOnRename": true`

Comment: As of author of the package said, this is a preview feature, he concludes that you can only move files to refactor work, you have to wait for the analyser finish refactor for you to move the next file. You can't move a whole folder of files yet, it won't work.  https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-11/